# Maximum scene allow in single standalone build

Tags: build, unity-game-engine, scene

I am trying to build **500 scene** in a single build but each time i fail and unity becomes close and no standalone player made. What is the limit of scene in a single standalone player? I am developing it for windows while using Unity 5.3 version

Comment: what do you mean with "each time i fail"? can you attach your Unity Editor Log?

Comment: where i can find this file

Comment: For windows: %localappdata%\Unity\Editor\
For OSx: ~/Library/Logs/Unity/

Comment: For testing purpose I just created more than 700 scene using control D couple of times and build the project but nothing interesting  happen like crash or error. (using unity 5.4)